# How do I perform a negative lookaround search

Tags: regex

I'm looking for all instances of a certain character in a string of text except for when it is both prefixed and suffixed a certain way.

A simple example of this would be to find all instances of "a" in the string "I am a cat in a hat in a car" except where it appears in the word "cat":

```
I am a cat in a hat in a car
```

Combining a negative lookbehind assertion and a negative lookahead assertion doesn't seem to work because it fails when either of the assertions are triggered rather than only when both are triggered.

Using a regex to find "a"s but ignore "ca"s ignores the word "car":

```
/(?<!c)a/g
```

```
I am a cat in a hat in a car❌
```

Using a regex to find "a"s but ignore "at"s ignores the word "hat":

```
/a(?!t)/g
```

```
I am a cat in a hat❌ in a car
```

Combining the two ignores both "car" and "hat":

```
/(?<!c)a(?!t)/g
```

```
I am a cat in a hat❌ in a car❌
```

Regex seems to NOR the two assertions, is it possible to NAND them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can nest the lookarounds, matching a and assert that to the left is not `ca` that is followed by `t` and use word boundaries `\b` to prevent a partial word match.

```
a(?<!\bca(?=t\b))
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/XFjBsw/1)

Or written with the lookbehind first, asserting not `c` to the left:

```
(?<!\bc(?=at\b))a
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/heAgLY/1)

Comment: Thanks, I wasn't aware that they could be nested

Answer (score 1):

You can use the exception token `[^...]` and alternate between both positive lookarounds: `/(?<=[^c])a|a(?=[^r])/g`.

By setting two exceptions in an OR, it's like a NAND gate and 2 NOT gates:

1. They both have to be true in order for it to be no match  1 and 1 => 0
2. Only one exception needs to be false so there is a match 0 and 1 => 1
3. If both are false then there's a match as well                     0 and 0 => 1

| Segment | Meaning |
| --- | --- |
| `(?<=[^c])a` | Match literal "a" if there is anything BUT a literal "c" before it |
| `|` | OR |
| `a(?=[^r])` | Match literal "a" if there is anything BUT a literal "r" after it |

https://regex101.com/r/CWV0ff/1